# I have problem with python code in google colab

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I can't solve this error in Google Collabs. Please find the error below.
[image: Collab Error Image]

Comment: Check your validation_split parameter

Answer (score 0):

The error states that you put an invalid keyword argument called validation_split for fit_generator.

**fit_generator() method** takes the following arguments, validation_split is not a valid argument for fit_generator.

```
fit_generator(
    generator, steps_per_epoch=None, epochs=1, verbose=1, callbacks=None,
    validation_data=None, validation_steps=None, validation_freq=1,
    class_weight=None, max_queue_size=10, workers=1, use_multiprocessing=False,
    shuffle=True, initial_epoch=0
)
```

validation_split is found in the **fit() method**.

```
fit(
    x=None, y=None, batch_size=None, epochs=1, verbose=1, callbacks=None,
    validation_split=0.0, validation_data=None, shuffle=True, class_weight=None,
    sample_weight=None, initial_epoch=0, steps_per_epoch=None,
    validation_steps=None, validation_batch_size=None, validation_freq=1,
    max_queue_size=10, workers=1, use_multiprocessing=False
)
```

Comment: @walaamasoud What did you change?